# creating gradient of a field as a derived field in project yt

Tags: yt-project

I need a little help creating a derived field which will return me the negative gradient of gravitational potential, hence the gravitational acceleration.
I tried something like this:

```
@derived_field(name = "gradient_gravpot", units = " cm/s**2")
def _gradient (field, data):
        G = add_gradient_fields(("gas"," gravitational_potental"))
        return (- data["gravitational_potential_gradient_x"])
```

and I got this error

```
   NameError: global name 'add_gradient_fields' is not defined
```

please suggest me the right method to define the field. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you got an answer [on the yt project mailing list](http://lists.spacepope.org/pipermail/yt-users-spacepope.org/2016-June/007948.html). That said, I'll repeat here that `add_gradient_fields` is a method of the `Dataset` class, so you will need to call it on a loaded dataset. For example:

```
ds = yt.load('path/to/dataset')
ds.add_gradient_fields(('gas', 'gravitational_potential'))
```